# Logout facebook user via oauth redirection

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a solution to logging out a user who has been authenticated via a oauth redirection url (not the js sdk FB.login call).

Calling the below (which other SO posts advise) doesn't work, it just returns me to the FB homepage (still logged in)

> https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[url]&access_token=[token]

I can use the JS sdk on the oauth callback but not to make the initial FB.login call.

Any solutions?

Comment: Are you using any sdk? php-sdk?

Comment: updated my question - I can use the JS sdk on the oauth callback but not to make the initial FB.login call

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**FB.logout**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/), to logout the user from facebook.

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
   // user is now logged out
});
```

Comment: only if you have initiated the auth via FB.login which I can't do and have to use the oauth redirection url. if there is a way to init the FB sdk from the access token I get back from the oauth callback then I can call FB.logout but I can't see a way to init the sdk with the access token?

Comment: But I think you can logout using the FB.logout. It may happen that the access token may not  be invalidated, but how's that important?

Comment: you can't, you get an error saying no access token as the FB sdk didn't start the login process so it doesn't know what the access token is. I was hoping there is a way to set the access token in FB.init or similar but can't find anything

Comment: If there is a session somewhere (e.g. you server side app) with a valid access_token, the JS SDK can process it. You need to set `cookie` and `status` to true in the init function. This of course only works, if you are on the same domain.

Comment: any idea how you tell the JS SDK the access token?